# Should I use a single database connection for my PySIde application?

Tags: python, sql, database, pyside

I am writing a GUI application with PySide. It has a few tables that get populated with data from a database, by pushing the corresponding buttons.

I thought of using a single database connection when the application starts and pass `conn` and `cursor` as variables in any functions that concern the database:

```
import sqlite3

database_fullpath = self.get_database_fullpath()
conn = sqlite3.connect(database_fullpath)
cursor = conn.cursor()

def populate_table(self, conn, cursor):
    # do something
```

Maybe, I should connect to the database everytime it's needed:

```
import sqlite3

def populate_table(self):
    database_fullpath = self.get_database_fullpath()
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database_fullpath)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    # do something
```

I am not sure which is the right approach and what the advantages of the different methods are.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to provide a helper class that reuses the connection if available and reconnects if not:

```
class SqliteDb(object):
    def __init__(self, db_fullpath):
        self.db_fullpath = db_fullpath
        self.conn = None
    def connect(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_fullpath)
    def cursor(self, factory=sqlite3.Cursor):
        try:
            return self.conn.cursor(factory=factory)
        except (AttributeError, sqlite3.ProgrammingError):
            self.connect()
            return self.conn.cursor(factory=factory)
    def close(self):
        self.conn.close()
```

Then in your code:

```
database_fullpath = self.get_database_fullpath()
sqlite_db = SqliteDb(database_fullpath)
cursor = sqlite_db.cursor()
```